# Line Break <br> Doesn't Work

Tags: c#

I am writing an web application. I have two pages in my application. In my first page when the user entered something invalid in the text box, it will display some message like this.

```
*EmployeeID is invalid.
*EmployeeID is already exist.
*Invalid Format
```

And here is my code

```
if (some condition occur){
    errMsg = "*EmployeeID is invalid. <br>";
    errMsg += "*EmployeeID is already exist. <br>";
    errMsg += "*Invalid Format. <br>";
}
```

My first page work fine, it displayed the errMsg correctly. However, when it redirect to the other page where user can edit the existing employee's information, it does not work.

This is my code in Employee_Edited.aspx

```
 if(some condition occur){
        errMsg = "*EmployeeID is invalid. <br>";
        errMsg += "*EmployeeID is already exist. <br>";
        errMsg += "*Invalid Format. <br>";
    }
```

It displayed something like this

```
*EmployeeID is invalid.<br>*EmployeeID is already exist.<br>*Invalid Format. <br>
```

Why does this happen? Help will be appreciated

Comment: How are you actually writing the string? Also, it should be `<br/>` or `<br></br>`, not `<br>` - though that might not make a difference depending on the browser.

Comment: @Rob `<br>` is fine in HTML.

Comment: @jdphenix You're right - I thought some older browsers would interpret it incorrectly, but it appears I'm incorrect

Comment: @Rob is on the right track. I suspect how ever you're writing that string out is escaping HTML.

Comment: It is obvious that in the second page, the error messages are displayed by assigning the errMsg variable to the innerText attribute of an element. In the first page it is probably the innerHTML attribute. Can you please check on this?

Answer (score 2):

Special chars in your Error Message (< and >) seems to be replaced by the matching HTML Code: &lt; and &gt;

Comment: Are there any way to fix this? Or is it just a bug?

Comment: @DragonBorn You need to edit your question and explain how you're writing out your HTML.

Comment: I suspect you have an `HtmlEncode` before returning to the client your response: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: string message = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("the message <br>");

Comment: I have tried either HttpUtility or Server.HtmlEncode, but all it does is change <br > to &lt;br&gt;

Comment: Hey guys, I have figured it out, as it turns out, I use `.InnerText` to display my text where I should've used `.InnerHtml`  instead.